# Wave equation in a medium PDE

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics

Suppose there is a string in a medium that applies a resistant force per unit length proportional to the velocity of the string. How do you write the equation of string vibrations?

Comment: If the displacement of the string is $u(x,t)$ then the velocity is $u_t$ the acceleration is $u_{tt}$ and the curvature is $u_{xx}$. How are the acceleration and curvature related when there is no resistive force?

Answer (score 2):

The wave equation with damping is
$$
u_{tt}=c^2\,u_{xx}-k\,u_t, \quad c>0,\quad k>0.
$$
The dumping term is $-k\,u_t$, $k>0$, proportional to the velocity of the string and in the oposite direction.